# calculating the following integral using Fubini

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

> $\frac{1}{Vol({x \ | \ s.t. |x|\le1})}\int_{|x|\le1}|x|^p = ?$

So I saw the following solution-

Let $E=\{(x,z)|0\le z\le 1-|x|^p\}$ be subset $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

So we know that $Vol(E)=^{1}\int_{|x|\le1}(1-|x|^p)$

Using Fubini,and knowing that $0\le z \le 1$,Knowing such $z$,we can look at the cut $|x|^p \le1-z$,or $|x|\le(1-z)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

So:

$Vol(E)=^2\int_0^1(\int_{|x| \le (1-z)^\frac{1}{p}}1 \ dx)=\int_0^1Vol(B_n(1))(1-z)^\frac{n}{p}dz=Vol(B_n(1))\int_0^1(1-z)^\frac{n}{p}dz=Vol(B_n(1))\int^1_0t^\frac{n}{p}=Vol(B_n(1))\frac{1}{\frac{n}{p}+1}=Vol(B_n(1))\frac{p}{n+p}$

And yet I don't understand those equations which are marked with $=^1,=^2$.

can anyone help???

Comment: Almost assuredly, those are footnote references. If you find the footnotes, they will probably give more explanation as to why the equailities are true.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What do you mean footnote references? I marked the $=^1,=^2$,it wasn't originally in the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted "quesations" to be a mis-spelling of "questions" and thought your question was why these were marked with  1 and 2. I guess now that that "quesations" was supposed to be "equations"?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Indeed,sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mystery here. 
First, 
$$E = \{ (x, z) : |x| \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq z \leq 1 - |x|^p \}.$$

Hence, 
$$
\text{Vol}(E) 
= 
\int_{|x| \leq 1} \int_{0 \leq z \leq 1 - |x|^p} \text{d}z \text{d}x
=
\int_{|x| \leq 1} (1 - |x|^p) \text{d}x
.
$$

Also, 
$$E = \{ (x, z) : 0 \leq z \leq 1 \text{ and } |x| \leq (1 - z)^{1/p} \}.$$

Hence,
$$
\text{Vol}(E) 
= 
\int_{0 \leq z \leq 1} \int_{|x| \leq (1-z)^{1/p}} \text{d}x \text{d}z
= 
\int_0^1 \left( \int_{|x| \leq (1-z)^{1/p}} \text{d}x \right) \text{d}z
.
$$

No?